# Using newInstanceWithoutConstructor for alternative constructors

Tags: php

PHP doesn't have function/method overloading, so I'm stuck creating static methods for alternative constructors. However, I still want to have a `__construct` method, I just don't want to call it when a static c'tor is used, so I came up with this:

```
public static function instance(\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $resp) {
    /** @var static $new */
    $new = (new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class()))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
    $new->body = $resp->getBody();
    $new->statusCode = $resp->getStatusCode();
    $new->reasonPhrase = $resp->getReasonPhrase();
    $new->protocolVersion = $resp->getProtocolVersion();
    $new->setHeaders($resp->getHeaders());
    return $new;
}
```

How bad is this? Are there any gotchas I should watch out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would design the constructor in a way that it *can* be called from all static alternatives. Probably the current constructor is doing too much?

However, since PHP 5.4 [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) supports the method, [`newInstanceWithoutConstructor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php), so there is nothing *bad* with that.

Comment: I usually prefer doing that, but sometimes I just don't want the functionality provided by `__construct` or I'd have to overwrite all the properties it sets anyway.

Comment: I think for exactly that reason the method was added in PHP5.4. But it always depends on the actual use case. Also I need to admit that I didn't knew about that method before. Before there was a way to fetch objects of custom classes from PDO queries without calling the constructor. Seems that developers liked that also for other use cases.